# jQuery - Select groups of three

Tags: jquery

I have found a few similar questions, but none seem to address my problem exactly. I am using an equal height column js function, but need to apply this to every row of three columns. They aren't contained in a row div, as it is responsive so the number changes, so I need jQuery to group every three elements and apply the function to them. The function loops through the selected elements, finds the tallest one and applies the CSS height to them all.

Considering the html:

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="column"></div>
 <div class="column"></div>
 <div class="column"></div>
 <div class="column"></div>
 <div class="column"></div>
 <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

The first 3 columns have to have equal height, the next 3 have to have equal height etc. So I have to select them and apply the function somehow. For now I am doing the following as it only has two rows, but I need to scale it so it can cater for more rows:

```
equalSize('.column:lt(3)');
equalSize('.column:gt(2)');
```

So I need something like:

```
equalHeight($('.column:everyThree???');
```

Comment: what do you want to do every 3rd column?

Comment: if ($("table > tbody").find("> tr:first > td").length == 3) { equalHeight($(this);}

Comment: I've updated the question which should hopefully make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

**updated**

```
var x = 1;
var max = $('.column').length;
var n = max % 3;

$('.column').each(function(){
    if(max!=(max-n)){
        if(x % 3 == 0){
            //your resize function
        }
        x++;
    }else{
        //do somethin about the extra elements.
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't want to change something on the third of each row - I need to select the first 3 elements and apply a function to them, select the next three and apply a function to them etc....

Comment: Then you would need to use `$.each` function similar from the oyher answer. I cant really modify my answer right now since im on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Right ok I've got this working, but thought there might be a quicker jQuery way. I also need to factor in remaining rows, if there are 2 on the end:

```
var x = 1;
var elems = [];

$('.column').each(function(){
  elems.push($(this));

  if(x === 3){
    equalSize(elems);
    x = 1;
    elems.length = 0;
  }else{
    x++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but its still not what I need. In my example you can see I have grouped each 3 .columns into an array - your example still treats each column individually, which is not what I want.